# Compare numbers in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, numbers

Having issues comparing 2 response codes in shell. Running curl and need to validate if response is between 200 and 400. Also, there is a chance of response to be "000" when a server is down.

```
#!/bin/sh
response1="200" #curl first url
response2="000" #curl second url

if (( $response1 -ge 400 || $response1 -lt 200 || $response2 -ge 400 || $response2 -lt 200 )) ; then
  echo "Something went wrong, response code is not in success range"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Success"
  exit 0
fi
```

> ((: 200 -ge 400 || 200 -lt 200 || 000 -ge 400 || 000 -lt 200 : syntax error in expression (error token is "400 || 200 -lt 200 || 000 -ge 400 || 000 -lt 200 ")

If I change the brackets to the [[...]] it always returns true.
If I change -lt to < and -ge to >= getting the following error:

> ((: 200 = 400 || 200 < 200 || 000 = 400 || 000 < 200 : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= 400 || 200 < 200 || 000 = 400 || 000 < 200 ")

Comment: change `((` to `[[` (and `]]`).

Comment: The operators used within `((...))` are documented at
[Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic).
The operators used within `[[...]]` are documented at
[Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Comment: How do your run your script? According to the #! line, it's not a _bash_ script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong operator. Correct way of writing is:

```
if (( response1 > 400 || response1 < 200 || response2 > 400 || response2 < 200 )) ; then
```

No need to explicitly dereference with `$`, als long as it is ensured that your variables contain just integer numbers.

Comment: ((: response1  400 || response1 < 200 || response2  400 || response2 < 200 : syntax error in expression (error token is "400 || response1 < 200 || response2  400 || response2 < 200 ")

Comment: What do you get when you do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` just in front of the `if` statement?

Comment: @MykytaShvets From the error message, you are missing the `>` operator in the `response1 > 400` and `response2 > 400` parts of the expression.

Comment: Thanks, after running in different environment with appropriate bash version - this works

Answer (score 2):

Please try with:

```sh
if [ $response1 -ge 400 ] || [ $response1 -lt 200 ] || [ $response2 -ge 400 
 ] || [ $response2 -lt 200 ] ; then
  echo "Something went wrong, response code is not in success range"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Success"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this should be the accepted answer. The code snippet in the question explicitly uses `#!/bin/sh` which is (almost?) always dash, and not bash, shell.